# Firefox incompatibility?

Tags: javascript, firefox, compatibility

http://ahmedstudio.za.pl/firefoxerror/

It works in chrome, opera but doesn't get along with Firefox.
The whole javascript thing is not applying.

This is directly in my javascript.js:

```
window.onload = function() {

        todo("body", 50);
        alert("alert!");

        setTimeout(function () {
            todo("body", 0);

        }, 1000)

}

function todo(element, size) {
     //blahblah
 }
```

Comment: Can you link to the whole page? Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: "ReferenceError: loading is not defined"

Comment: it works in mine. Try installing firebug and ensure that no other scripts are giving the error. firebug will actually tell you where the error is, unless there is a syntax error.
notepad++ has a pylint extension - install that and you can get rid of syntax errors before tearing your hair out.

Comment: There is no `loading` identifier in the code that you have shown. Do you use that in the `todo` function?

Comment: http://ahmedstudio.za.pl/firefoxerror/
here, i put it up on my hosting

Comment: the 'loading' error was just a function i forgot to delete from html
but still don't know what's the problem with firefox

Comment: What happens if you remove the `onload="loading()"` from your `<body>` tag?

Comment: You are replacing all onload handlers with an invalid function call. When trying to fix the mess, it's possible that other browsers refuse to redefine `onload` and the rest of the code works by pure chance.

Comment: BTW, what's the scripting supposed to do? I see exactly the same static page in Firefox and Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it doesn't actually solve your problem I'd like to share my findings about replacing event handlers with invalid function calls. I've composed this little [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/vobifakigu/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(function(){
      $("body").on("load", function(){
        $(this).append("Should not run")
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="doesNotExist()">

</body>
</html>
```

Firefox, Explorer and Edge actually replace the `<body>` event handler. However, Chrome ignores the `onload="doesNotExist()"` and execute previous handler.

In the land of tag soup it's hard to decide which workaround is the correct one but it's definitively a bug that could explain your symptoms.

Comment: Assuming jQuery is just using addEventListener (which, from memory, they are), per-spec they should fire the event such that all listeners are called. Therefore, the Chrome behaviour is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
function load() {
        //do stuff
}
```

and the appropriate

```
<body onload="load()"> </body>
```

Comment: He's already using jQuery. It doesn't make much sense to get back to 1997 and inline even handlers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This runs fine in me. I even tried to create a dummy page with this snippet but could not replicate it.Here is snippet.Since the snippet you shared does not contain jquery , i opt to use same code .

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
            _todo({
                a:'body',
                b:50,
                alertFrom:'window.onload'
            });
        setTimeout(function(){
             _todo({
                a:'body',
                b:0,
                alertFrom:'setTimeOut'
                  });   
            },1000);
        };

        function _todo(options){
            var a = options.a;
            var b = options.b;
            var c=options.alertFrom
             alert(c +" "+a +" "+b);
            };
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that there is a importance of semicolon after a function.
Here are couple of snapshots
[image: Alerting on load]

[image: Alerting after 1 sec]